# Metro App resolution on Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-runtime

I have been working on win RT application for few months. Now I have upgraded to Windows 10 & checking for compatibility. I am stuck at an issue wherein the windows scales the app to make maximum use of space available but due to that some of the text goes unreadable in high resolution devices. So, is there anything that I could do inside the app in order to prevent the issue.

FYI:

I read about Effective Pixels (epx) but don't know how to use it using XAML & C#

The thing I need to achieve is that the text & images must look of the same size irrespective of the screen resolution i.e disabling the scaling done by windows in Windows 10.I checked the application on Windows 8.1(resolution 1600x900) & Windows 10 (resolution 1600x900), but the contents looked smaller on Windows 10 but ideally it should look same as I used same resolution device with same settings.

Images for your reference

Windows 8.1 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0urv.jpg
Windows 10 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIkJc.jpg

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Effective Pixels is standard in Windows 10. If you want to work around it, you really have to do some work.

Using effective pixels means that Windows will scale the UI appropriately to the device. So the differences between phone, tablet or big TV screen are handled automatically.

Make sure you use the right controls to scale you app best. There are some techniques to determine how your app will respond. Have a look at [this Reponsive 101 article in the Windows 10 design guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn958435.aspx).

In VS2015 or Blend (or the emulator) you can test various resolutions or scaling factors. Where you might have a problem is in the used graphic in the background. If no other resolutions are provided, the system will scale the one he has. For instance, have a look at this article [on scaling the splash screen image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465338.aspx).

Martin

Comment: we have handled the background graphics but the problem arises with the fonts & other images used.